# PHP - Count the time with microseconds, react on a whole second

Tags: php, time

I`m using the php command microTime(true) to retrieve time from the server.

I would like to fire off an event every time an complete second is reached, I need accuracy of microsecomds to determine when a complete second is reached.

This is the code i have so far:

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

while($someValue){
    if(microtime(true)==time()){
        echo "<p>".microtime(true)."</p>";
        echo "<p>".time()."</p>";
    }

    //sleep for one microsecond
    usleep(1);
}
```

Can someone help or explain to me how to get this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using usleep only once?

```
usleep(1000);
```

Are you sure that it will be less precise? I don't see how...

Answer (score 0):

this code work for me better than yours

```
$time = time();
while (true) {
        $curtime = time();
        if ($curtime > $time) {
                $time = $curtime;
                echo microtime(true), "\r\n";
        }
        usleep(1);
}
```

You cannot be sure, that processor have time for your process in each microsecond.